# mongodb aggregate $sum returns extra floating point digits

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sum

I am looking to sum the price of some inventory items via their skus on my nodejs server. They are floating-point numbers. My documents look like this

```
[ 
    { 
        quantity: 1,
        price: 38.95,  
        sku: 'C-2177',
        product: 55b9cfc5fa39110bb644becc,
        _id: 56739191b98d1fde79c3034e 
    },
    { 
        quantity: 1,
        price: 24.95,
        sku: 'C-2188',
        product: 55b9d013fa39110bb645100d,
        _id: 5743870e139e80b9ecb48e02 
    } 
]
```

All my prices are defined in my schema as Numbers. When I try the $group $sum operators like this:

```
InventoryItem.model.aggregate([
    { $match: { 'sku': {$in:['C-2177', 'C-2188']}}},
    { $group: { 
        _id: null, subtotal:{$sum:'$price'}
    }}
], function(err, results){
    console.log(results);
});
```

I get extra floating point digits. Here the sum adds up to $63.90, but I get a response like

```
[ { _id: null, subtotal: 63.900000000000006 } ]
```

I'm using mongoose 4.4.2 with the mongodb 2.1.18 driver and my server is running MongoDB 2.6.11. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are the normal rounding errors of floats. Try in node:

```
> var a = 38.95, b = 24.95; console.log(a + b)
63.900000000000006
```

To avoid that, do not store prices in $, store them in cents. If you have really huge numbers, use a library like `bigInteger` and store the results as strings.

Comment: Thanks! I had noticed prices as cents in the past but I did not understand the reason behind it.